# Old FPS planet explorer game similar to Mass-Effect-1 and HALO-1

Tags: identify-this-game

This is at least 18 years old FPS PC game, has similar missions and graphics as of Mass-Effect-1 and HALO-1. Weapons and enemies are also silimar, but gameplay felt better.

**Story-line -**

- Game begins showing a team traveling in space using a earthly made space-craft.
- They receive a mission from a radio message(from a military general) regarding an ancient weapon. Parts(artifacts) of this weapon have been scattered around different planets within a galaxy, and they needed to collect them all to complete this weapon.
- Main character goes to various alien planets to collect these artifacts. Had to fight local enemies with earthly and alien weapons. Normal missions similar to Mass-effect and HALO.
- Near the end of the game, the team realises that the military general has plans to take this weapon by himself, and this ancient weapon is too powerful which shouldn't fall into hands of anyone.
- In the last mission which was on a large space-ship, the main character gets the last artifact of the weapon, kills the military general who was already there, puts all parts of weapons on the space-ship and sends it to the nearest star to get destroyed.
- In that last mission while trying to escape the space-ship, there were alien enemies who were twice or thrice a human's size and their left hand could launch black-portal/black-hole which pulls nearby items into it. It would deal an instant d_e_ath.

The game is more like HALO during gameplay, and is like Mass-Effect in non-playable scenes.
Non-playable scenes are very few compared to Mass-Effect.

That is all I know about this game. Tried many internet searches, watched gameplays of similar games hoping that recommendations would contain this game. Couldn't find any clue about this game.

The game I am looking for is not -
BioShock, Crysis, Far-Cry, Red Faction, DOOM, Dead Space, Resistance, COD, Wolfenstein, Half-Life, Gears Of War, Destiny, Splitgate, Singularity, Star Citizen.

Comment: You've named a third person shooter (Mass Effect) and a first person shooter (Halo). It would really narrow the search down if you could say which of the two games it was more like.

Comment: @knol updated the description to include the FPS word. 
The game is more like HALO during gameplay, and is like Mass-Effect in non-playable scenes. 
Non-playable scenes are very few compared to Mass-Effect.

Comment: You might want to try asking on https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmyjoystick/ as well.

Comment: ...as well as the #identify-a-game channel on the MobyGames Discord.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very likely *[Unreal II: The Awakening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unreal_II:_The_Awakening)*, released in 2003.

From the plot section on Wikipedia,

> The player controls John Dalton, a former Marine veteran of the Human-Skaarj War and Marshal of the Terran Colonial Authority. His job is to patrol remote areas of space far away from any real action. However, he is called back into service when *an ancient artifact is discovered in a ransacked mining facility* on Elara V. This artifact is later revealed to be *one piece of seven* which, when assembled, create an ancient and powerful weapon.

I'm mostly going off of memory here; I haven't played it since it was released. The story does involve the protagonist going to multiple different worlds to collect the pieces of the artifact. He is a human and is mostly given human weapons, but the ship's mechanic is able to retrofit some of the weapons/technology from the encountered hostile aliens to act as new weapons.

Between planets the player can freely move around the ship and interact with the other crew members. This would be the mass-effect like sequences. The interactions are very minimal, just talking to them and listening to their stories. There's no romance options or anything similar.

[This YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pgNK4IORtKQ) covers the final mission, where the general plans to use the artifact for himself. Invoking the artifact transforms previously docile and pacifist aliens that were a background presence on multiple worlds into fearsome monsters; a bossfight against one can be seen at 3:28. It can be seen using the mentioned black hole gun; this is severed during the bossfight and can then be used against it, and against other similar monsters.

Comment: This is it. Even though it is from the popular Unreal series, I can't believe I forgot it's name. Thanks for the answer.